# data restructuring in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset looks like this. 4 variables which contains 5 cases in a transaction format.

[image]

I would like to create variables for for Account field with current_Bal value in it like below.

[image]

How can I achieve this in R?

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem? Do you have samples of your coding we can help you with?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in this way:

```
get_val <- function(acc_type,check_type,val){
    return(ifelse(acc_type == check_type,val,NA))
}

df$Account_Draft_Current_Bal <- get_val(df$Account,'Draft',df$Current_Bal)

df$Account_Savings_Current_Bal <- get_val(df$Account,'Savings',df$Current_Bal)
```

## Update:

We can also do this using `dcast()` function by:

```
library(reshape2)

dcast(df,CustID + Account + Open_Bal + Current_Bal~ Account,value.var = 'Current_Bal')
```

Comment: I was struggling to do this by using dcast() function and this solves the problem for me . thanks!

Comment: @TeddyKim I have also included the `dcast()` function solution. You may refer to it as well.

Comment: @Kunai Puri I also tried dcast function and it keeps on giving me "Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length" As a result, somehow row numbers differ after casting.. where am I going wrong here?

Comment: @TeddyKim I agree with your point that the row numbers are differing. It is producing the output by applying ordering on the LHS part of the formula specified. If you don't want to change the order, you can use the alternative that I gave you initially.